# terminal command rspec spec/controllers/teams_controller_spec.rb is timing out

Tags: rspec, rspec2

I was running this command successfully until I was just about to start the last spec in the file (describe'DELETE #destroy' do). Now when I run the command listed in this question's title, it appears that my terminal freezes or times out.

Here are my associated files and terminal output.

[image]

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

'ruby' '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '3.2.14'
gem 'pg'
gem 'devise'
gem 'composite_primary_keys'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-datetimepicker-rails'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', git: 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier',     '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', require: false
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'pry-remote'
  gem 'guard-zeus'
  gem 'guard-rspec', require: false
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

spec_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'factory_girl_rails'
require 'shoulda'
require 'shoulda-matchers'


# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  # FactoryGirl.find_definitions
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"
end
```

factories/teams.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :team do |f|
    f.name 'Bengals'
    f.sport_type 'softball'
    # f.university_id '1'
    f.association :university
  end
end
```

teams_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe TeamsController do
  describe 'GET #index' do
    before(:each) { @university = FactoryGirl.create(:university) }

    it 'returns http success' do
      get :index, university_id: @university.id
      expect(response).to be_success
    end

    it 'assigns every team object into an @teams array' do
      @team = FactoryGirl.create :team, university_id: @university.id
      get :index, university_id: @university.id
      expect(assigns(:teams)).to eq [@team] and be_success
    end

    it 'renders the index template' do
      @university = FactoryGirl.create :university
      get :index, university_id: @university.id
      expect(response).to render_template(:index)
    end
  end

  describe 'GET #new' do
    before(:each) { @university = FactoryGirl.create(:university) }
    it 'returns http success and instantiates a @team' do
      @university = FactoryGirl.create :university
      @team = FactoryGirl.create :team
      get :new, university_id: @university.id, id: @team.id
      expect(@team).to be_a_kind_of Team
    end

    it 'renders the #new template' do
      @university = FactoryGirl.create :university
      get :new, university_id: @university.id
      expect(response).to render_template(:new)
    end
  end

  describe 'GET #create' do
    context 'given valid credentials' do
      before(:each) { @university = FactoryGirl.create(:university) }

      it 'returns http success and redirects to the #show template' do
        @university = FactoryGirl.create :university
        post :create, team: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:team), 
        university_id: @university.id
        team = Team.order(:created_at).last
        expect(response).to be_redirect
      end
    end

    context 'given invalid credentials' do
      before(:each) { @university = FactoryGirl.create(:university) }

      it 'returns http client error' do
        post :create, team: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:team), 
        university_id: @university.id
        team = Team.order(:created_at).last
        expect(response).not_to be_success
      end

      it 'should render the #new template' do
        post :create, university_id: @university.id
        expect(response).to render_template(:new)
      end
    end
  end

  describe 'GET #show' do
    before(:each) { @university = FactoryGirl.create(:university) }

    it 'returns http success and renders the #show template' do
      @team = FactoryGirl.create :team
      get :show, university_id: @team.university_id, id: @team.id
      expect(response).to be_success
      expect(response).to render_template(:show)
    end
  end

  describe 'GET #edit' do
    before(:each) { @university = FactoryGirl.create(:university) }

    it 'returns http success and renders the #edit template' do
      @team = FactoryGirl.create :team
      get :edit, university_id: @team.university_id, id: @team.id
      expect(response).to be_success
      expect(response).to render_template(:edit)
    end
  end

  describe 'GET #update' do
    before(:each) { @university = FactoryGirl.create(:university) }
    it 'returns http success and redirects to the #show template' do
      @team = FactoryGirl.create :team
      get :update, university_id: @team.university_id, id: @team.id
      expect(response).to eql 200
      expect(response).to be_redirect
    end
  end

  describe 'DELETE #destroy' do
    it 'should destroy object from the database and redirect to teams_path' do
      delete :destroy, university_id: @team.university_id, id: @team.id
      expect(@university.delete).to be_true
      expect(response).to redirect_to universities_path
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after adding all of the files, so I figured it best to post an answer in case someone else runs into this. This is a nested controller, and by that I mean that it has a parent association with University.rb. I was having difficulties getting both id's (University and Team) to get filled in properly, and the more explicit I became, the various errors stopped coming up.

I realized that by accessing the parent association's id through the descendant's instance variable I was able to locate the proper resource like so:

```
get :show, university_id: @team.university_id, id: @team.id
```

I was able to get the earlier specs to find the proper resource by being less explicit, and when I was at the end of this spec file, my guess is that it began to complain about my earlier implicit id finds

```
get :show, [@university, @team]
get :show, university_id: @university.id, id: @team.id
```

Hope this helps someone in the future. Time to go prepare for thanskgiving.